# Whitespaces handler in Liquid not working

Tags: liquid, azure-api-management

I cannot figure out how to remove whitespaces from the start and end of my strings. 
My response body is:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "nomeUnidadeOperacional": " ",
            "nomeCaixaPostalComunitaria": " ",
            "nroCaixaPostal": " ",
            "enderecoCaixapostal": " "
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using "| split" and "{%- assign item = body.value[0] -%}" as the documentation for liquid explain "whitespace control". 
My set-body:

```
<set-body template="liquid">
    {
        "Endereco": {       
            {% assign item = body.value[0] %}
            "caixaPostal": {
                "nome": "{{item.nomeCaixaPostalComunitaria | strip }}",
                "numero": "{{item.nroCaixaPostal | strip }}",
                "endereco": "{{item.enderecoCaixapostal | strip }}"
            }
        }
    }
</set-body>
```

What I'm getting:

```
{
    "Endereco": {
        "caixaPostal": {
            "nome": " ",
            "numero": " ",
            "endereco": " "
        }
    }
}
```

What I expected:

```
{
    "Endereco": {
        "caixaPostal": {
            "nome": "",
            "numero": "",
            "endereco": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Sure i could use a if to test if the content is " " and replace it after, but i could have more than 1 whitespace and this option isn't elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On API Management you need to write the Filter Capitalized.

```
"nome": "{{item.nomeCaixaPostalComunitaria | Strip }}",
```